# Is it possible to have a templated type not known at compile time

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class:

```
template <unsigned M, unsigned N, typename T = float>
class Matrix
{};
```

I want to read from a file which contains matrices of some unknown M,N and create the above type:

Matrix getMatrixFromFile(std::string &path);

Is this possible given that M, N are not known at compile time?

Comment: No, not possible. And you really don't "have a class". You have a *template*.

Comment: No. You want/need to rewrite your class so (for example) M and N as passed as parameters to the ctor instead.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

The templates parameters are used to create types at compile time based on the types passed.

Comment: There is a way of doing that, though :) One can write a program that generates and compiles another program... But yeah, probably not what OP is looking for!

Comment: @VladLazarenko, The number of times I've thought of that possibility just as a possibility, albeit not a very promising one, is a bit too high for my liking.